# Passing to child component an event handlers within slot in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I created a couple of reusable components with a slot within it. So I can manage the content, style, or whatever it is anytime I call it, in other components. I wonder, can I passing an event handler to
those components but inside the template tag?

**ReusableComponent**

```
<a :href="hrefProps"> // I want the handler goes here
  <slot></slot> // it will render plain text, without html tags
</a>
```

**Main Component**

```
<reusable-component>
  <template @click="sayHelloWorld">Hello World!</template> // didn't work
</reusable-component>
```

How can I make that to work? Should I wrap them into at least 1 tag, like

```
<template><a @click="sayHelloWorld"></a></template> // sure it will working
```

Comment: did you tried by adding `v-slot:default`

Comment: I thought <template> and <template v-slot:default> are the same, if we dont specified the name in the tempalate, it will render as a default slot

Comment: i guess you render a normal template https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template and its invisible my default. take a look into the console if you can see something

Comment: console doesn't show anything if I put a listener inside template tag. is not a big deal anyway, I could simply just wrap them inside one html tag or  pass the handler as a props in my reusable component, and bind that <a> tag with v-bind $attrs, but you know, brain farts. Just wonder can I do that

Comment: `sayHelloWorld` is defined in parent or child component?

Comment: offcourse, and with my case, I don't need to define that method inside my child component. cause in my thoughts, the base from reusable components have to be as static as possible. I don't wanna add methods on components that I call almost every single time.

Comment: I think it is the basics motivation using tools like vue. because they allow you to boilerplate components right? like include method in php, but this one, is reactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Template tags** don’t create a **DOM element**, so pi can’t add a listener to them, or add a class or anything else.

They are just a semantic tool to wrap multiple children in a loop.

Add the listener to the real parent element i-e **href** tag

Comment: yeah so unfortunate. makes slot functionality less enjoyable. imagine inside <a> tag there's a span element that rendered from parent element just to make this things work.